# H2 not storing username, password and role

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-security, h2

The problem is that h2 only stores the properties from my class User but fails to store the properties username, password and authorities from Spring Security's User class.

Here is my class for user:

```
package com.netcetera.videoverification.persistence.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Setter
@Getter
public class User extends org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String email;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    public User(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
    }

    public User(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, String email,
                String firstName, String lastName) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

The code for the repository:

```
package com.netcetera.videoverification.persistence.repository;

import com.netcetera.videoverification.persistence.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,Long> {
}
```

This is the service:

```
package com.netcetera.videoverification.service;

import com.netcetera.videoverification.persistence.model.User;
import com.netcetera.videoverification.persistence.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public boolean create(String username, String email, String password) {
        String passwordHash = new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(password);

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        User user = new User(username, passwordHash, authorities, email, "First", "Last");

        this.userRepository.save(user);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Screenshot of the db entries:
[DB entries screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63STi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because hibernate didn't see inherited fields since superclass is not marked with `@MappedSuperclass` annotation.

You may try to switch hibernate access mode from fields to property, but it will not work either since password field in `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` is `private`, without setter at all and other fields are `private final` which makes hibernate unable to update them in any way.

I can suggest instead of extending `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` create `username`, `password` and `roles` fields by yourself and then just implement `UserDetails` interface if you need to pass an instance of this class somewhere else (where spring security userdetails object expected).